# Implementing an Event Map like WWDC 2012 App

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, uiimage, wwdc

Although I haven't actually used it, I've seen pictures of the WWDC 2012 app in which it appears each workshop was given its own location on an event map. Is this simply a UIImage with a pin drop?

[image]

I also found this local mapping startup: http://gigaom.com/mobile/wifarers-mobile-app-doesnt-just-map-the-indoors-it-maps-the-objects-within/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of venues at WWDC is always pretty small -- perhaps around 20 including the labs. And there are only three floors in Moscone West. You could certainly do that sort of map with a set of three images and a pin superimposed in the correct location for each venue. That seems like the simple solution.

Comment: My app would be mapping lots of events along with multiple pins on each event. The image thing definitely wouldn't work in my case, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some library I'm missing out on. Good observation, though. Thanks